# My Hadoop interview scenario based query -solution can be in HIVE/PIG/MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig

I have data in a file like below(comma(,) separated).

```
ID,Name,Sal
101,Ramesh,M,1000
102,Prasad,K,500
```

I want the output table to be like below

```
101, Ramesh M, 1000
102, Prasad K, 500
```

i.e Name and Surname in a single column in the output

In Hive if I give row format delimited fields terminated by ',' it will not work. Do we need to write a serde?

Solution can be in MR or PIG also.

Comment: Can we see any attempts you made edited into your question? There is generally an expectation on this site that _some_ prior effort or research is demonstrated.

Answer (score 3):

Why you dont use [concat](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) function, if you dont want process data and just query the raw data, think about creating a [view](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateView) on it :

```
select ID,concat(Name ,' ' ,Surname),Sal from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use concat function.

First, You can create the table(i.e. table1) with raw data having 4 columns delimited by comma :

```
ID, first_name,last_name, salary
```

Then concat the first_name and last_name using select query and store the results in another table using [CTAS(Create TABLE AS SELECT)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS)) feature

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_TABLE AS SELECT ID, CONCAT(first_name,' ','last_name) as NAME, salary from table1
```

Comment: The same answer I have told the interviewer :D, He dint accept this.